# Spry validation text field not displaying well in google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, adobe, spry

I am using spry validation text field in a project and the error message does not display well in google chrome but it displays well in mozilla firefox.I would want the error message to display in google chrome the way it displays in firefox.

This is the way the error messages display in firefox.[image]

google chrome,

[image]

CSS Styling of the error messages

```
 display: inline;
        color: #CC3333;
            border: 1px solid #CC3333;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding-left:8px;

            padding-right: 8px;
            font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: block;` in the place of  `display: inline;`
It will work fine.

```
display: block;
        color: #CC3333;
            border: 1px solid #CC3333;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding-left:8px;

            padding-right: 8px;
            font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
```